# MATLAB figure badly scaling by rotating 3D object

Tags: matlab, 3d, figure

This is what happens: first run this:

```
total = linearArray('NumElements',2,'PhaseShift',[180 0],'ElementSpacing',5e-2);
```

Now look at bad disaster that happen by this:

```
arrayFactor(total,100e6)
```

Now you can see how badly it resize by rotating the object:
[image][image]

But I have seen something that is nicely rotate without bad automatic resizing, you can see it by running this:

```
pattern(total,400e6,'azimuth',-180:1:180)
```

Comment: Some info for people that wonder like I do: these commands belong to the Antenna Toolbox, which is an official MathWorks product. (I had never heard of it.)

Comment: Does setting `axis equal` fix this issue?

Comment: If your axis aren't equal (thus what @CrisLuengo says doesn't work), you can call `axis manual` after the first figure call, [freezing the axes in their current state](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html)

Comment: @CrisLuengo after `arrayFactor(total,100e6)` I have run `axis equal`, but no change. :(

Comment: @Adriaan I've used `axis vis3d` and the problem solved, thx.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `axis vis3d` and the problem solved, Thanks to Adriaan